# How to get the id of an ImageButton?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm developing a solution that passes the one activity for other activity after the user clicks in an `ImageButton`. I have 6 images and all images 
 are having the same `onClick` event and I need to distinguish different `ImageButton`'s clicks which is which for passing for the second activity.
I tried the solution below, but the line with `idImageButton.tag.toString()` doesn't work.

**file.kt**

```
fun onclickImage(view: View){
    val idImageButton:ImageButton = view as ImageButton
    val pokemonName:String = idImageButton.tag.toString()

    val myIntent = Intent(this, Details::class.java)
    myIntent.putExtra("pokemon", pokemonName)
    startActivity(myIntent)
}
```

Comment: log `idImageButton.tag.toString()` and see what it logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to checked the `id` of the view to distinguish them. For Example if the `id` of the `ImageButton` for which you want to move to the second `activity` is **pokemon**, then try like this.

```
fun onclickImage(view: View) {

    if(view.id == R.id.pokemon) {
        val myIntent = Intent(this, Details::class.java)
        myIntent.putExtra("pokemon", "Pokemon")
        startActivity(myIntent)
    }
}
```

If you also want to do it by `tag` you have to set `tag` in either xml or code. Then you can check it with `tag`

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/pokemon"
    android:tag="Pokemon"
    android:onClick="onclickImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then check `tag` and take decision.

```
fun onclickImage(view: View) {
    val pokemonName = view.tag.toString()

    if(pokemonName.equals("Pokemon", true)) {
        val myIntent = Intent(this, Details::class.java)
        myIntent.putExtra("pokemon", pokemonName)
        startActivity(myIntent)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get view id with casting to ImageButton

```
when(view.id) {
            R.id.btnFirst -> {}
            R.id.btnSecond -> {}
            //so on
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 val button:ImageButton
       val id =  button.id
```